# How to specify which overloaded function I want in Typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm trying to promisify standard node fs.writeFile. I have typings for both node and bluebird which is my Promise lib of choice here:

```
const f = Promise.promisify(fs.writeFile)
return f(file, content); // Should be a promise
```

This does not work because:

> [ts] Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
>   const f: (arg1: string) => Promise<{}>

So i chooses the wrong overloaded method because the call to promisify can't really know which I guess. Or maybe it's not even that, but something with the optional arguments, because these are the three overloaded writeFile:

```
export function writeFile(filename: string, data: any, callback?: (err: NodeJS.ErrnoException) => void): void;
export function writeFile(filename: string, data: any, options: { encoding?: string; mode?: number; flag?: string; }, callback?: (err: NodeJS.ErrnoException) => void): void;
export function writeFile(filename: string, data: any, options: { encoding?: string; mode?: string; flag?: string; }, callback?: (err: NodeJS.ErrnoException) => void): void;
```

promisify has lots of overloads for # of args and looks like this:

```
/**
 * Returns a function that will wrap the given `nodeFunction`. Instead of taking a callback, the returned function will return a promise whose fate is decided by the callback behavior of the given node function. The node function should conform to node.js convention of accepting a callback as last argument and calling that callback with error as the first argument and success value on the second argument.
 *
 * If the `nodeFunction` calls its callback with multiple success values, the fulfillment value will be an array of them.
 *
 * If you pass a `receiver`, the `nodeFunction` will be called as a method on the `receiver`.
 */
static promisify<T>(func: (callback: (err:any, result: T) => void) => void, receiver?: any): () => Promise<T>;
static promisify<T, A1>(func: (arg1: A1, callback: (err: any, result: T) => void) => void, receiver?: any): (arg1: A1) => Promise<T>;
static promisify<T, A1, A2>(func: (arg1: A1, arg2: A2, callback: (err: any, result: T) => void) => void, receiver?: any): (arg1: A1, arg2: A2) => Promise<T>;
static promisify<T, A1, A2, A3>(func: (arg1: A1, arg2: A2, arg3: A3, callback: (err: any, result: T) => void) => void, receiver?: any): (arg1: A1, arg2: A2, arg3: A3) => Promise<T>;
static promisify<T, A1, A2, A3, A4>(func: (arg1: A1, arg2: A2, arg3: A3, arg4: A4, callback: (err: any, result: T) => void) => void, receiver?: any): (arg1: A1, arg2: A2, arg3: A3, arg4: A4) => Promise<T>;
static promisify<T, A1, A2, A3, A4, A5>(func: (arg1: A1, arg2: A2, arg3: A3, arg4: A4, arg5: A5, callback: (err: any, result: T) => void) => void, receiver?: any): (arg1: A1, arg2: A2, arg3: A3, arg4: A4, arg5: A5) => Promise<T>;
static promisify(nodeFunction: Function, receiver?: any): Function;
```

So it seems it rather the wrong promisify that is being used. Is there any cleaner way for me to achieve what I want? Currently I have to resolve to this:

```
const writeFile : (filename: string, data: any, callback: (err: NodeJS.ErrnoException) => void) => void = fs.writeFile
const f = Promise.promisify(writeFile)
return f(file, content);
```

which I feel is very ugly and verbose…

Comment: Related https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/304

Answer (score 7):

I haven't been able to set up a good simple working example, but the following type assertion would allow you to hint and what you would expect:

```
const f = <(file: string, content: string) => void> Promise.promisify(fs.writeFile)
```

You can amend `<(file: string, content: string) => void>` to better describe what you expect to be available, or use the wider type `<Function>` or go dynamic with `<any>`.

The first option is a little more work, but will allow the return type to be inferred when you later call `f` (in this case `void` - but you can imagine cases where this return type will be used more vigorously).

Based on your comment, I'm guessing you'll need...

```
const f = <(file: string, content: string) => Promise<any>> Promise.promisify(fs.writeFile)
```

You could also use a union type in place of the `any` in this example, if you know the two possible outcomes, i.e. `Promise<any>` could be:

```
Promise<ErrnoException | MySuccessfulType>
```

This will allow a return type of `Promise<ErrnoException>` or a return type of `Promise<MySuccessfulType>`.

Comment: Yeah, it can't return void after promisify, nor any. I'm trying to expand on your example with `const f = <(file: string, content: string) => Promise<NodeJS.ErrnoException>> Promise.promisify(fs.writeFile)` but that fails miserably with 

error TS2352: Neither type '(arg1: string) => Promise<{}>' nor type '(file: string, content: string) => Promise<ErrnoException>' is assignable to the other.
  Type 'Promise<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<ErrnoException>'.
    Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ErrnoException'.
      Property 'name' is missing in type '{}'.

Comment: In your case, you may have to be more liberal with the last bit. Examples added.

Answer (score 3):

you could use `__promisify__` from `fs.writeFile` namespace:

```
fs.writeFile.__promisify__(file, content)
```

Otherwise, you've to explicitly mention generic types to pick corresponding overload:

- [Node](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) built-in `util` package has a `promisify()` function

```
const f = util.promisify<PathLike, string, void>(fs.writeFile)
f(file, content)
```

Answer (score 0):

What I end up doing is specifying myself the overloading type, the main con of this method is that once the library updates I won't be notified.

Example with mixpanel:

```
const mixpanelClient = Mixpanel.init(mixpanelProjectApiToken, {
    protocol: 'https',
});

type trackFunc = (eventName: string, properties: PropertyDict) => Promise<void>;

const track: trackFunc = promisify(mixpanelClient.track.bind(mixpanelClient));
```